# Player Ranks look really bad, how to optimize

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I want to make 3 tables with player rankings (I want to add a picture of the class and some other information there), but after taking the working tables and adding information from 1 database, I see that there is a lot of no needed code, which I don't know how to remove ...

I also have a problem, because under the tables I have a gray line that looks terribly ugly.

Thank you for all the help!

```
<?php include_once "settings.php";
//Ranking

//p1
$query0 = "
    SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 0,1
    ";
$result0 = mysqli_query($db, $query0);
$row0 = mysqli_fetch_row($result0);

//p2
$query1 = "
    SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
    ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);

//p3
$query2 = "
    SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 2,1
    ";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
//p4
$query3 = "
    SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 3,1
    ";
$result3 = mysqli_query($db, $query3);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);
//p5
$query4 = "
    SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 4,1
    ";
$result4 = mysqli_query($db, $query4);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_row($result4);

//Strona
head("Ranking");
?>
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 20px;">
                <div class="btn_main">
                    <div class="btn_before">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="btn_center"><span>Ranking graczy:</span></div>
                    <div class="btn_after">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                        <div class="container">
                                            <header>
                                                <div class="btn_main">
                                                    <div class="btn_before">&nbsp;</div>
                                                    <div class="btn_center"><span>Easy:</span></div>
                                                    <div class="btn_after">&nbsp;</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                <table align="center" class="tablea" border="1"
                                                       style="border-color:#343434" cellpadding="0"
                                                       cellspacing="1">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th> P</th>
                                                        <th> Gracz</th>
                                                        <th> Cześć</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">1</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row0[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row0[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">2</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row1[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row1[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">3</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row2[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row2[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">4</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row3[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row3[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">5</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row4[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row4[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                        <div class="container">
                                            <header>
                                                <div class="btn_main">
                                                    <div class="btn_before">&nbsp;</div>
                                                    <div class="btn_center"><span>Medium:</span></div>
                                                    <div class="btn_after">&nbsp;</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                <table align="center" class="tablea" border="1"
                                                       style="border-color:#343434" cellpadding="0"
                                                       cellspacing="1">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th> P</th>
                                                        <th> Gracz</th>
                                                        <th> Cześć</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">1</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row0[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row0[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">2</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row1[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row1[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">3</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row2[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row2[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">4</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row3[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row3[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">5</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row4[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row4[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                        <div class="container">
                                            <header>
                                                <div class="btn_main">
                                                    <div class="btn_before">&nbsp;</div>
                                                    <div class="btn_center"><span>Hard:</span></div>
                                                    <div class="btn_after">&nbsp;</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="wrapper">
                                                <table align="center" class="tablea" border="1"
                                                       style="border-color:#343434" cellpadding="0"
                                                       cellspacing="1">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th> P</th>
                                                        <th> Gracz</th>
                                                        <th> Cześć</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">1</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row0[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row0[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">2</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row1[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row1[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">3</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row2[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row2[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">4</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row3[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row3[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="poz">5</td>
                                                        <td class="Gracz"><?=$row4[0]?></td>
                                                        <td class="Cześć"><?=$row4[1]?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <BR>
                <BR>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
foot()
?>
```

Comment: When you say: _I see that there is a lot of s**t here_, could you try to be a little less poetic and be specific about what it is that you do (not) want rendered?

Comment: @jibsteroos sorry for that, i mean too much code in my file, maybe there is a solution to shorten it all, use less $ query etc. The tables are just fine, but there is a ton of code ...

Comment: When you tale your select and Limit it to 4 you have all you need for tun it in a while loop, bu your source code don't doesn't explain what is the difference between medium and hard. From that there are more possiblitys first union easy mdium and hard in one select statement and run a llop so that it displays everything nce and easy. but first i have to undestand how the differ.

Comment: @nbk well Easy Medium and Hard be a mode of servers i will run they will have separate databases

Comment: It doesn't matter, where the data is as long as they are reachable and the resukt have the same structure.     SELECT name, honor
    FROM players
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 4 union all     SELECT name, honor
    FROM playersmedium
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 4 union all     SELECT name, honor
    FROM playershard
    ORDER BY honor DESC
    LIMIT 4

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$thisquery = "SELECT name, honor FROM players ORDER BY honor DESC LIMIT 0,4";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$thisquery);               
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $resultArr[] = array($result["name"],$result["honor"]);
}

echo "<table id='mytable'>";
    echo "<tr><td>Position</td><td>name</td><td>honor</td></tr>";
    $i=0;
    foreach($resultArr[] as $key => $value) {
        $i++;
        echo "<tr><td class=\"poz\">$i</td>
                  <td class=\"Gracz\"><?= $value[0] ?></td>
                  <td class=\"Cześć\"><?= $value[1] ?></td>
              </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

In your CSS you can style like this:

```
table #mytable td {
    background: #eee;
}
```

(Code not tested, just typed, so beware of typo's.)